# I have an unusual chess set and am seeking advice

Tags: chess-set

As suggested, I have reworded my question. Hope this is more appropriate.

[image: Picture of the King]  [image: Picture of the Knight]

Many years ago (circa 1988/89) I had commissioned and made a chess set of key characters from the American Independence (American, French and British figures).

This is a one-off (the casts were broken after use) and is hand crafted/painted, made from solid pewter.

I have a data sheet for the set (albeit photocopy quality) detailing the pieces. This set has never been used so the condition is mint.

I was collecting sets for quite a few years and did intend to display this one but never got round to it.

What I am after is advice from the forum as to what to do? I have stopped playing and collecting a long while ago. It's not that I am not a fan of chess but lack a regular playing partner and work consumes so much of my time (particularly when travelling), I can never seem to get the time to even set them on display on the few boards I have.

Sensible comments appreciated.

Thanks

p.s. for information/interest I have uploaded pictures of the set I have described in this post

Comment: Sell on ebay...?

Comment: I don't think this question is on-topic here, but I would suggest getting in touch with an antiques dealer for any older sets.

Comment: Also, you can sell on Amazon.

Comment: Or sell on Etsy for home made sets.

Comment: Or Craigslist...

Comment: Gumtree is also an option.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping someone might recommend a dedicated chess seller online rather than eBay.

Comment: I will try the antique dealer suggestion though as this sounds like a possibility.                     Herb - you need to get out more

Comment: Actually, this sight, specifically for people who care enough about chess to ask bizarre questions about arcane chess moves, would be a pretty good place to find a buyer for what sounds like a nice antique.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the buying or selling of chess sets is a commercial venture and not a chess venture ..

Answer (score 1):

Amazon, ebay, and top local online shop in your country

Comment: Welcome to Chess SE! Ideally, we're looking for answers which are more than just a single line. For example, you could list the pros and cons of each option.